# creating nested route without a nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails app with user profiles that provide contact details for the user's office. I want to show a map to the user's office, but the maps are too large for the profile page, so I want to give visitors the option to view the map on a new page like this

```
localhost:3000/userprofile/2/map
```

I know that if I create a map resource and nest it like this

```
  resources :user_profiles do

     resources :maps
  end
```

I'll get the map url above automatically.  However, I don't think I need a full resource for maps, since it's just using information (i.e. address) that's already in the user profile for Google's map api.

Therefore, I created a route like this

```
 match "/user_profiles/:user_profile_id/map" => "user_profiles#map", :via => :get
```

But when I did 'rake routes' to find out what the route helper (for example, user_profile_reviews_path for the user/reviews resource) would be, it didn't give me one. I don't know how to create a link that will open on `user_profile/id/map`

Is it possible to do what I'm doing, or should I just create a Map resource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Add a new RESTful resource](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions):

```
resources :user_profiles do
  get 'map', :on => :member
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. One small problem. Using this `<%= link_to 'Office Map', map_user_profiles_path(@user) %>` is creating this link  `localhost:3000/user_profiles/map.37-username` which is a problem because it's putting the map before the id of the user.  Am i misunderstanding something?

Comment: @BrainLikeADullPencil Is `@user` an instance of a `user_profile`?

Comment: No, it's a bit more complicated. There's really no such thing as user_profiles It's actually more specific. I changed some details for the purpose of the question. The profiles are specific to profession such as doctor_profile_path, however, there's an association between the doctor_profile resource and the user model, so that i've been able to create links like this so far without a problem: doctor_profile_path(current_user)

Comment: @BrainLikeADullPencil Then this won't work, a path helper for user profiles expects a user profile.

Comment: Thanks. Does that mean you wouldn't expect this to work (which it does)  `doctor_profile_path(answer.user)`? it finds the doctor_profile path based on the user (which has_one doctor profile) retrieved through  the association with the doctor's answer.  This works in my app.

Comment: @BrainLikeADullPencil Depends on the route definition, which I can't see.